# How can I solve this partial differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm modeling the dynamic localization, after solving the Helmholtz equation I obtained this partial differential equation, if anybody can give me a guideline I would be truly grateful.

\begin{equation}
i \alpha(y) \frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2} + \beta(y) \frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}  - i A \cos(x) u(x,y) = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: Have you considered the typical methods? For example Fourier analysis or trial functions? Or even looked at Arfken?

Comment: yeah,it was obtained after using the DFT.

Comment: What are conditions for $\alpha(y), \beta(y)$? What about $A$? Are you sure you need the general case, maybe some examples of what $\alpha(y), \beta(y)$ can be?

Comment: By the way, what are the boundary conditions?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

this is a right answer that we obtained that with mathematica!!
Mathieu function is the answer.

Comment: In your original question, you write $\alpha(y)$ and $\beta(y)$, which suggests that they depend on $y$. However, the equation you wrote into Mathematica has $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as constants. That is, the solution you got is only valid if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are indeed constants

Comment: this constants coming from physical concept of my equation,in general i think we can not solve the equation without simplification, fortunately cause of the physical condition of my problem equation has solved!!